# Heroku: "directory exists" error after changing requirements.txt

Tags: python, django, heroku

For one of the libraries I use, I'm trying to switch from a `mercurial` repository to `git`. Unfortunately when I tried to push the project with new `requirements.txt` file, I get this:

```
Obtaining django-storages from git+https://github.com/richleland/django-storages/#egg=django_storages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Directory /tmp/build_3lujzy9ddaetm/.heroku/src/django-storages already exists, and is not a git clone.
  The plan is to install the git repository https://github.com/richleland/django-storages/
What to do?  (i)gnore, (w)ipe, (b)ackup Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Forcing it with `push -f` ends with the same message. How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was fixed by Heroku team by pushing a new Python buildpack, using `wipe` as the default for this kind of conflict.